# Email blank values

Tags: php, html

Hi everyone I have a form here that sends an email to a person when a new contact is added.

Everything works. The user gets added to the database, the email is sent but the email is blank:

Eg. Staff:
    Extension:
    Email: 
    Cellphone:

Iv tried a few ways around and the emails are always blank could someone help with this if possible?

my code:

```
<?php 
    require_once"connection.php";
?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$to = "???@????";
$from = "???@???";
$subject = "New Staff Added To Extension List";
$message =  "New Staff: " . "\n\n" . "Name : " . $name . " " . "\n\n" . "Email: " . $email . " " . "\n\n" . "Department: " . $department . " " . "\n\n" . "Extension: " . $extension . " " . "\n\n" . "Cellphone: " . $
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers); 
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php include"includes/head.inc"; ?>
    <script>tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">

            <!-- header section -->
            <div class="header">
                    <div class="headerContent"><h1>CONTACT LIST</h1></div>
            </div>

            <!-- content section -->
            <div class="content">
            <div><h1>Create New Contact</h1></div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="contact">
                            <div class="contact_insert">
                                    <form action="insert_contact.php" method="post">
                                            <table style="float:left" width="50%">
                                                    <tr>
                                                            <td>Name:</td>
                                                            <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name"  size="40%"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                            <td>Email:</td>
                                                            <td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" size="40%"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                            <td>Department:</td>
                                                            <td><input type="text" name="department" placeholder="department" size="40%"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Extension Number:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="extension" placeholder="extension" size="40%"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                            <td>Cellphone:</td>
                                                            <td><input type="text" name="cellphone" placeholder="cellphone" size="40%"></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            <div class="clear"></div>
                                            <input class="insert_contact_button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert Contact">
                                            <a href="index.php"><input class="cancel_contact_button" type="button" value="Cancel"></a>
                                    </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
            </div>  
</body>
</html>         
<?php 
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $department = $_POST['department'];
            $extension = $_POST['extension'];
            $cellphone = $_POST['cellphone'];

              $insert_contact = "insert into contacts (name, email, department, extension, cellphone) values ('$name', '$email', '$department', '$extension', '$cellphone')";

            $sql_insert_contact = $conn->query($insert_contact);

            if ($sql_insert_contact == true) {
                    header("Location: index.php");
            }
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: You are trying to access variables that you only set value later in the code... Can you spot that?

Comment: Try taking the code from the top and putting it after the insert (before redirect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you execute this line:

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Before you declare the variables it depends on.  Only later in the code do you set them

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$department = $_POST['department'];
...
```

It's ok to declare them on top, before the `mail` function

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])):
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   ...
   mail(...);
endif;
```

Comment: Sidenote: submitting the form is no guarantee that every needed input's been filled.

Comment: And, a 'correct' idea would be to only send the email if  the `insert` works.. Otherwise someone might get an email that doesn't correspond to reality.

Comment: You're right; there is lots more that can be done (eg: validating email and phone #s, using prepared statements, filtering out bot submissions...), but these are not relevant to what was wrong. I tried to write a simple answer though that gives enough info for the asker to find out why his script wasn't working.  It's good that you point these out though, for someone who may not be aware.

Comment: Yep The op can read the comments and figure out by themselves... They are just sidenotes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Below is your code

```
$message =  "New Staff: " . "\n\n" . "Name : " . $name . " " . "\n\n" . "Email: " . $email . " " . "\n\n" . "Department: " . $department . " " . "\n\n" . "Extension: " . $extension . " " . "\n\n" . "Cellphone: " . $
```

**There is a `$` symbol at the end. I think it is an error.**

Please rewrite it as

```
$message =  "New Staff: " . "\n\n" . "Name : " . $name . " " . "\n\n" . "Email: " . $email . " " . "\n\n" . "Department: " . $department . " " . "\n\n" . "Extension: " . $extension . " " . "\n\n" . "Cellphone: " . $Your_value_if_any;
```

**Important Note:** Add your email code after the sql. There is no value assigned for many of the variables like `$name`, `$email`, etc.

Comment: Besides from that, the op is trying to read a variable that doesn't even have a value at the reading point..

Comment: @FirstOne, yeah. I forget to add that. Thank you for make me noticed that

Answer (score 0):

I have create above code on mine. It is working perfect. Please check this.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $insert_contact = "insert into name (name) values ('$name')";
    $sql_insert_contact = $conn->query($insert_contact);

    $to = "To email";
    $from = "From Email";
    $subject = "New Staff Added To Extension List";
    $message =  "New Staff: " . "\n\n" . "Name : " . $name;
    $headers = "From:" . $from;

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    header("Location: index.php");
}
```